# move the cursor C

Tags: c

The same code, but it gives me results different between the ways run the program.
Who can explain to me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("\x1b[%d;%dH", 11, 11);
    printf("Hello world");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised that you're surprised that `printf("\x1b[11;11H");` prints a weird character followed by `[11;11H`.

Answer (score 1):

The program is emitting [terminal control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) which tell the console to move the cursor.  Different terminals respond to these codes differently, which is why you get different results when you use different terminals.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that the control codes escape sequence is not supported in the shell left, it is supported in the right shell.
Or when you run the executable directly, it does not allocate the same console as run in cmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

This is why we have ncurses and similar libraries